# How to copy (or print) msbuild variable from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild

[image: Visual Studio Include Properties MSBuild Macros]

Is there a way, in Visual Studio, to copy the contents of a MS Build Macro variable. For example $(TargetDir) ( alas Ctrl-C, right-click does nothing ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you need those values? Really on the clipboard, or somewhere else?

Anyway you can get a hold of the value by using the macro in the build process somewhere. For instance to display it so it's copyable, you could add a post-build event that does `echo $(TargetDir)` and you'd see the value printed in the Output Window and you can copy it from there. Or you can do it outside of VS by making an msbuild file that imports your project, then uses the Message task to display any property. You could even use inline C# code to copy the value directly to the clipboard.

Another way is to define an External Tool (under Tools menu), use `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe` as command and something like `/c echo TargetDir = $(TargetDir)` as argument. Check the `Use Output window` box. Now your tool appears in the tools menu, and if you click it prints the target directory to the Output Window.

Answer (score 1):

Just chiming in to say that after some muddling around, I was able to successfully print some MSBuild variables to the console (during execution) by adding this block inside my `<Project>`:

```
  <Target Name="EchoSomeVars">
    <Exec Command="echo y| echo Some var: $(SomeVar)"/>
    <Exec Command="echo y| echo Some var 2: $(SomeVar2)"/>
  </Target>
```